# C - select() - how to update the timer correctly

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

The linux manual states that:

```
The operation of select() and pselect() is identical, other than these
       three differences:

       (i)    ...

       (ii)   select() may update the timeout argument to indicate how much time
              was left.  pselect() does not change this argument.
       (iii)  ...
```

It says that you can update it but how can i do that?
i call select() again, with the same parameters?

Comment: It is a linuxism: Linux always had a non-standard *feature* of updating the struct timestamp. Other unices did not do this, and it is not in POSIX, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says that you can update it but how can i do that

It says no such thing. It says **the function can modify it**. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) phrases it slightly different:

> Upon successful completion, the select() function **may modify the
>   object pointed to by the timeout argument**.

Comment: so if i call a select() with 10 sec. timeout when my thread starts, i cannot add some seconds to that timer during the execution of the thread, or reset it to 10 seconds?

Comment: @nickNatra I don't think you can. The standard doesn't say anything so that's what you should assume. Just handle the timeout as a "spurious wakeup".

Comment: @nickNatra I don't see how `utimensat` that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the contents of timeout structure during the call. However you can stop select, and restart it with a new timeout.

Usually, when you are making multi-threaded application with `select`, you provide a way to interrupt this call for updating list of processed file descriptors, for example. This can be achieved using a socket pair, for example. One socket of the socket pair is used for control thread, and another one is always added to `fd_set`. Though it is a different subject.

Comment: i'm using select() without any file descriptors, just as a thread-safe timer.

Comment: @nickNatra You can consider using wait functions (you can't modify wait), or timers (those ones can be amended).